# Writing regex to exclude time in a date

Tags: regex, concatenation

I am trying to write a regex to capture something but having a bit of trouble. The text is:

```
Generated from 10-16-2015 00:00 to 11-13-2015 23:59
```

I would like to capture 10-16-2015 to 11-13-2015. So basically I want to exclude the time in each one. I got it down to where I can capture the first date using:

```
(?<=Generated from )\d*-\d*-\d*
```

But how do I also include the second date and also the word "to"? within one regex. Any help is appreciated

Comment: You cannot do that with one regex match operation. Use 2 steps: match all the substring with the time, and then remove it using a replace operation. Or use capturing groups and concatenate their contents later.

Comment: so there is no way to output from this
10-16-2015 to 11-13-2015?

Comment: Just saw this whole comment now. I am not sure how to use replace functionality too much using regex. I typically only do matching in the way that I use regex. It seems like i do need to match the time up though and replace w blanks but not sure how. Any way to help direct me stribizhev?

Comment: if it matters, I am using expresso to do all of my testing

Comment: When writing comments and addressing someone, use `@`+`nick`. I have only noticed the comments now. Are you using C# or VB.NET? Please show your code. As I said, you can't do all that you want with pure regex. There is a way to do some cool tricks with .NET code, too.

Comment: @stribizhev unfortunately, I am not the developer of the application. I only have access to the config files where I input a regex and it will go in to the PDF to look for the anchor I have written to extract the info I need. I have no way to modify the code of the application. Is it possible to concatenate two regexs? One that gets the first date and one for the second?? these two:
(?<=Generated from )\d*-\d*-\d* 
and
 to \d*-\d*-\d* (?=\d*:\d*\r\nPt Name) <--note, this is the next line, Pt Name

Comment: You can do that if the app allows concatenating values obtained.

Comment: @stribizhev, I think it would but I am not sure how to write that expression all in one regex. I tried:
(?<=Generated from )\d*-\d*-\d*|to \d*-\d*-\d* (?=\d*:\d*\r\nPt Name)

using a pipe but that just makes expresso select between two alternatives, which i dont want. I looked up how to concatenate and I found some that say just put them next to each other, so i use the above w out a pipe and that just makes it so nothing matches in expresso

Answer (score 1):

Use [groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html):

```
^Generated from (\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4}) \d{2}:\d{2} to (\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4}) \d{2}:\d{2}$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/cT1bA0/1)

Answer (score 0):

I would use two capture groups and combine them. Something like [this](https://regex101.com/r/yX0wA3/2)

```
(?<=Generated from )(\d*-\d*-\d* )\s*\d{2}:\d{2}\s*(to \d*-\d*-\d*)
```

Comment: csmith, that works perfect except I do not want the time that comes with the first date either. Is there a way to get rid of that?

Comment: You just need to use whatever language you're using to get the correct capture groups. Here's an example using javascript: http://www.es6fiddle.net/iiqc58t0/.

Comment: The thing that stinks is I am not the developer of the application so not sure what he is using. As a front end person, we just write regular expressions to pass along to the application. I just know I need to capture the above so not sure. Would it help if I could concatenate two regexs? ie
(?<=Generated from )\d*-\d*-\d*
and
to \d*-\d*-\d* (?=\d*:\d*\r\nPt Name)   <--note, this is the next line